# Mysql syntax error when using an alias for a subquery

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, in-subquery

If i don't put aliases to the subqueries i get the error "Error Code: 1248\n Every derived table must have its own alias".
If i put aliases i get a syntax error near the alias ([...]syntax to use near ' bb[...]).

(The following code has been overly-simplified for clarity and pivacy reasons)

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM
    (SELECT id FROM
      stoc
    WHERE id_gest IN (SELECT ida FROM nom_gest) bb
      ) aa
```

I tried with the keyword 'AS' and without, i tried putting the alias in between quotes, i tried diferent paranthesis configurations and nothing.

I also tried just running it with just ONE subquery: it Works without an alias. but if i put an alias i get a syntax error near the alias([...]syntax to use near ' bb[...]).

Comment: Remove the alias `bb`

Comment: You don't even need the subquery: `SELECT max(id) FROM stoc WHERE id_gest IN (SELECT ida FROM nom_gest)`

Comment: i removed only that alias and it worked. weird. Thank You!

Comment: i know that i apparantely don't need that subquery but i just over-simplified the original because i'm not allowed to make public anything

Comment: Anyway, you must not alias subqueries used with IN

Comment: Presumably, there's a specific result you're trying to obtain from a given a data set. If so, let's focus on that instead. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sub query not a derived table so you don't need the alias so remove that bb.

```
WHERE id_gest IN (SELECT ida FROM nom_gest) bb
```

When you put a sub query in the FROM section it's a derived table.